# Rails ActiveRecords with own attributes + associated objects' IDs

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I have a rather simple ActiveRecords associations like such (specifically in Rails 4):

- An organization has many users
- A user belongs to an organization

But in terms of ActiveReocord queries, what's an optimal way to construct a query to return an array of Organizations each with its own array of user ids associated with itself? Basically, I'd like to return the following data structure:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Organization id: 1, name: "org name",.... user_ids: [1,2,3]>, <Organization id: 2...>]>
```

... or to distill it even further in JSON:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'org name', ... user_ids: [1,2,3]}, {...}]
```

where `users` is not part of the Organizations table but simply an attribute constructed on the fly by ActiveRecord.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** After trying a few things out, I came up with something that returned the result in the format I was looking for. But I'm still not sure (nor convinced) if this is the most optimal query:

```
Organization.joins(:users).select("organizations.*, '[#{User.joins(:organization).pluck(:id).join(',')}]' as user_ids").group('organizations.id')
```

Alternatively, the JBuilder/Rabl approach @[Kien Thanh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081668/kien-thanh) suggested seem very reasonable and approachable. Is that considered current best practice nowadays for Rails-based API development (the app has the back-end and front-end pieces completely de-coupled)?

Comment: You should take a look this screencast [Jbuilder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?view=asciicast) to create JSON data like what you want.

Comment: I was looking for a straight up ActiveRecord association query. But Jbuilder/Rabl seem cleaner and easier to digest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing to be aware of with a library solution such as `JBuilder` or `Rabl` is to watch the performance when they build the json.

As for your query use `includes` instead of `joins` to pull the data back.

`orgs = Organization.includes(:users)`

You should not have to group your results this way (unless the group was for some aggregate value).

`ActiveRecord::Relation` gives you some automatic helper methods, one of which is `association_ids`.

So if you create your own JSON from a hash you can do

```
orgs.map! {|o| o.attributes.merge(user_ids: o.user_ids).to_json }
```

EDIT: Forgot to add the reference for `has_many` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

Comment: Unless raw performance is a concern, I've found that using libraries like Jbuilder, ActiveModelSerializers (if using Ember.js)... etc to be more efficient use of dev time for their ease of use, easy on-boarding, easy customization... etc. It was immediately obvious to me how hand-rolling custom JSON response formats was getting old after only a week of doing it myself. I missing having seasoned backend guys doing all this heavy-lifting for me. ;)

Comment: Agreed. I just ran into this isssue at the last company I worked at. RABL was making our API unusably slow. One of our engineers ended up self-rolling a responder set for us, so I always add the caveat at the beginning.